# Get geographic location from screen location

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I'm working on an application that uses google maps. Can I get the geographic location of a particular point on the screen?.For example, I have a view (button, image, etc) with a X and Y position on the screen. What I want to know is the geographic location (latitude and longitude) of that position (view position). 
Of course this position (X and Y) is on the map.

Comment: what do you mean? Like dropping a marker and getting details of that?

Comment: I want to get the latitude and longitude of a point on the screen (x, y). Of course that point is on the map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. This is how:

```
Projection projection = googleMap.getProjection();

// Returns the geographic location that corresponds to a screen location
LatLng geographicalPosition = projection.fromScreenLocation(new Point(your_X, your_Y)); 

// Returns a screen location that corresponds to a geographical coordinate 
Point screenPosition = projection.toScreenLocation(new LatLng(your_latitude, your_longitude));
```

More information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection.html).

Comment: But what is this screen position? I've tested it, and it provided me a weird value for Y : around 5000. This is way larger than value of the resolution height of the screen

Answer (score -1):

In short yes(your questions lacks details and your own attempt), I would drop a marker on the screen at my current location and set the marker property to draggable. This will allow me to move the marker to any position on the map

For example,

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(Your_Lat, Your_Lng))
        .title("My Marker")
        .draggable(true));
```

After placing it anywhere you want you can retrieve the markers new Latitude and Longitude by simply using the position function. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374329/get-latitude-and-longitude-of-marker-onclick).